# Multiple registration phases

Tags: 7, social-network, users

I'm having trouble figuring out how to have a registration in different phases. This is what I would like to do:

- A user registers with a name and an email or register with facebook.
  He will receive an email to set his password.
- The user can now bookmark nodes. But when he would like to create a node of content type Proposal he needs to complete a full registration (I'm using [Multi-step registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module). An email will be send to the administrator who needs to check the data and give the user a new role.

For now I have the second step. A user register with a complete form. But how can I add the facebook register or name/email register before it?

Comment: I Think you need to play with Roles here after step1 users have authenticated user role and after complete registeration they will have editor say another role & provide permission to add content to this role only(editor)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you should consider the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module for getting this to work.

Excerpt from [issue # 1796856](https://www.drupal.org/node/1796856#comment-8939935) :

> [Multi-Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module works out of the box with [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and all we need to do is assign the profile type to a particular step.

That same issue also contains some extra details about getting around possible access errors.

Refer to the [Community documentation of Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074296) for more details about this module.